# how do i print even numbers of sub arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var nestedArr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8],[9,10,11,12]];

function printEvens() {

    for(var i = 0; i < nestedArr.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < nestedArr[i].length;j++){
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                var arr = nestedArr.toString().split(',');
                console.log(arr[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
printEvens();
```

am I doing this right? or am i missing the mark? 
how would you solve this problem?

Comment: expected output would help

Comment: You mean even numbers or even indexes ? Because the title says even numbers but your code is going for indexes

Comment: because it returns this for some reason
1
 3
 4
6
 7
 9
11

Comment: There's no need to test whether `i` is even. Just increment it by 2: `for (var i = 0; i < nestedArr.length; i += 2)`

Comment: **expected output would help**

Comment: tried it but its doesnt return even numbers im trying to retrun:
2
4
6
8
10
12

Comment: `[].concat(...nestedArr).filter(v => !(v%2))` results in just the even **values** (only works for 2 level array)

Comment: `[].concat(...nestedArr).filter(v => !(v%2)).forEach(v => console.log(v))` results in console log of even numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**

The issue resides in the inner loop. You get the `string` representation of the whole array, to then `split` and get back another array:

```
var arr = nestedArr.toString().split(',');
```

They are already arrays, there is no need for splitting. You can directly access the positions you want. After splitting you access this array as a 2D array specifying 2 indexes:

```
console.log(arr[i][j]);
```

If you just `split` it, it only has 1 dimension, because `split` always returns a 1D array.

See the `split` result for yourself:

```js
var nestedArr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8],[9,10,11,12]];
console.log(nestedArr.toString().split(','));
```

Also testing `i % 2 == 0` would only show you even positions/indexes for the main array and not the sub array.

**Solution**

Only the `if` and `console.log` need to be adjusted in order to work:

```js
var nestedArr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8],[9,10,11,12]];

function printEvens() {

    for(var i = 0; i < nestedArr.length; i++) {
        for(var j = 0; j < nestedArr[i].length;j++){
            //no splitting just accessing directly the correct indexes
            if(nestedArr[i][j] % 2 == 0){ 
                console.log(nestedArr[i][j]); //nestedArr instead of arr
            }
        }
    }
}
printEvens();
```

A more interesting solution would be using a double [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with [*Arrow Functions*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which makes it a one liner:

```js
var nestedArr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8],[9,10,11,12]];

nestedArr.forEach(x => x.forEach(y => { if (y % 2 == 0) console.log(y); }));
```

Disclaimer: This last proposed solution uses ES6 syntax as show in the documentation links

Answer (score 3):

Below is an example of how you could do this.

```
function printEvens(array) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(array[i])) {
            printEvents(array[i]);
            continue;
        }
        if (array[i] % 2 == 0) {
            console.log(array[i]);
        }
    }
}

printEvens([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [[[13, [14]]]]]);
```

Comment: ES2015+ - `const printEvens = arr => arr.forEach(item => Array.isArray(item) ? printEvens(item) : (item % 2 ? void 0 : console.log(item)));`

Answer (score 1):

I would use reduce and filter to achieve what you need something like this:

```
let yourArray = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8],[9,10,11,12]];
let evenNumbers = yourArray.reduce((prevVal,currVal)=>{
  let value = currVal.filter(val => val%2===0);
  prevVal.push(...value);
  return prevVal;
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
var nestedArr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8],[9,10,11,12]];

for(var key1 in nestedArr){
    var item_nestedArr=nestedArr[key1];
    for(var key2 in item_nestedArr){
       if(item_nestedArr[key2] % 2 == 0){            
            console.log(item_nestedArr[key2]);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While question is bit ambiguous. @Barmar is right. You may simply increment iterator by 2.

```
function printEvens() {
    for(var i = 0; i < nestedArr.length; i += 2) {
        for(var j = 0; j < nestedArr[i].length; j++){
            console.log(nestedArr[i].toString(););
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a flattening algorithm here. If you can use a opensource library, [lodash.flattenDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#flattenDeep) can help. Otherwise you could do something like this:

```js
var nestedArr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8],[9,10,11,12]];

function flatten(ary) {
  return ary.reduce(
    (flattened, e) => 
      e.constructor === Array ?
        flattened.concat(flatten(e)) :
        flattened.concat([e]),
    []
  );
}

console.log(flatten(nestedArr).filter(n => n % 2 === 0));
```